# MySQL best approach to having one table tied to multiple tables?

Tags: mysql

I'm not too sure how to word my question, but here it is.

Let's say I have multiple tables, `dogs`, `cats`, and `birds`. Each of them have `uploads` related to them. Each can have many, so I figured it would be best to be on its own table.

Which is a better approach?

1. a single `uploads` table with `for` taking the table (say `dogs`), and `for_id` referencing the id of that column
2. a single `uploads` table with a columns `dogs_id`, `cats_id`, `birds_id`, with one of them filled with the relative id
3. multiple tables, named `uploads_dogs`, `uploads_cats` and `uploads_birds`

Or maybe there is a better appraoch?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a single uploads table with a type id (birds = 1, cats = 2, etc.) and an object id column containing the ID of the cat/bird/dog. So when you want to find all uploads for a given cat:

```
    SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE typeId = 2 AND objectId = [catId]
```